# How to send data from jnlp to web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, java-web-start, jnlp

I have deployed one web application, say **webAppA**.

I also have jar which contain couple of Swing classes. This jar(Swing classes) runs on client system through **jnlp**. They(Swing classes) do some image processing on the images which is present on client system.

Now, I want to send the data collected by Swing classes back to my web application **webAppA**.

How can I achieve this ? Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: HTTPUrlConection ? REST ? Webservice ? http post / upload ? There are lots of techniques.

Comment: @Marged *"There are lots of techniques."*  True.  And given the techniques are neither limited to, nor barred from use by, Java Web Start apps., this has much more to do with 'communicating with a web-app.' than it does with 'JWS'..

Comment: thanks @Marged for your reply. I am new to JWS so I thought there must be some 'direct way' for JNLP to talk to web application(coz deployment of JNLP is same  as web application).

Comment: but I guess JNLP program(in my case, Swing class) runs on client system so they wont have (direct) access to the web server.

Comment: @BhushanPatil unless the access is explicitly disallowed an outgoing connection to a webserver or the webserver the application was run from should be possible